# Multiple language on the DocuSign completed email notification (API in php)

Tags: docusignapi

We have integrated the DocuSign multiple languages (English, Chinese Japanese) in our system, and it works fine. But when a user used English to sign a contract and send it to the admin, the admin also received it in English. After both of them finished signing, the completed email notification is shown in different languages. For example, the admin will receive the subject, content, and footer all in English. The user will receive the content in English, but the subject and footer in (Chinese).

Comment: How did you set up the multiple languages? API calls or in the Admin UI?
Did you choose a set of languages for a brand by selecting languages in Admin->Brands->Edit [Specific Brand]->Set Brand Languages?
Or did you create resource files by concatenating resource files from different languages?
Or are your setting up languages for your envelope in some other way?

Comment: What do you want to happen?

Comment: I set up the multiple language using the API and i did setup the languages for my envelop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Language in DocuSign is, for the most part, dictated by the end-end-user. Meaning, the signer can choose what language they use when they sign a contract. So, if you build an integration and you do it in one language, and then your customer who is sending using your integration is using another language, neither of these have anything to do with the language that would be shown to the signer if they choose to use DocuSign in yet a third language.
That is, assuming all involved have an account, where they can log into DocuSign and change their language preference.
As a sender, you can change the language preference for the emails that are sent, but you cannot decide which language would be used to actually sign the document.

Comment: this is wrong and shouldn't be accepted

Comment: which part is wrong Milan?

Comment: the language of the signing page can be set by adding &locale=*your-desired-language-abbreviation*, but then the email that is sent will be in the language of the signature requester's account, not the signer's language. In order for the email to change, the requester's account needs to have a branding for different languages, and when creating envelope for the documents he needs to pass the branding, but then all recipients that have to sign that don't have account won't be able to choose their language with &locale, and everything (including the email) will be on the branding's language

Comment: I don't know if this is the desired behavior of docusign and the localization, but that is how it's working now (maybe there is a bug). If the requester has a branding with english and japanese enabled for the branding, and the account's language is in english, the &locale=ja will work for the signer's page, but the email received by the signer will be in english.

Comment: This may be a bug, let me have someone review this thread to see if this is a bug or not

Comment: @MilanPanic Please see Colin's answer here

Answer (score 1):

DocuSign tries to honor the language selected by the user as much as possible. There are a couple of ways that the supported languages can be limited and make it so the user sees a different language:

1. Branding: Brands can be configured to allow specific languages--a subset of the total supported languages at DocuSign. When using a branded envelope, if the user's language is not included in the set of brand languages, DocuSign applies the default brand language instead.
2. Overrides: The language of a signing session can be overridden using the query parameter `&locale`. This does not affect email notifications.

Without knowing more details of how your envelope was configured and what your user language selections were, it will be impossible to know if this is a bug or how to fix it. However, verify the following things:

- The set of languages in the brand includes the language of the user that is sending the documents. This can be tricky for English because there are two dialects of English supported for signers, but only one of those is supported in the eSignature application in general.
- Test with new email addresses. DocuSign keeps a record of the selected language with each email address.

Comment: When using English in a brand: I recommend selecting both English UK and English US.